# Pandas merging dataframes, overwriting values on key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My apologies if this question is a duplicate. I really cannot find the answer to this specific case. Is it possible to merge/join two dataframes, while overwriting the values in the first dataframe if the key ('id') also exists in the second dataframe?
Kind of like the 'INSERT - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' command in SQL.

The first dataframe 'df1':

```
    id      value
0   100010  25
1   100011  22
2   100012  30
```

The second dataframe 'df2':

```
    id      value
0   100012  35
1   100013  36
```

Merging the dataframes results in new columns and keeps the old data for 'id' '100012':

```
df3 =  pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='outer')
print(df3)

    id      value_x value_y
0   100010  25.0    NaN
1   100011  22.0    NaN
2   100012  30.0    35.0
3   100013  NaN     36.0
```

Is it possible to get to the desired output directly from the merge function? So only 'id' '100012' is updated and new row '100013' is added?

```
    id      value
0   100010  25
1   100011  22
2   100012  35
3   100013  36
```

I've tried [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join), [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) and [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), all without success. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. `set_index` id, 2.  `pd.concat`  3.  `reset_index` 4. drop duplicates `subset = 'id', keep= last`. Thats it. I can give you the code but try for yourself once. :)

Comment: Dark, Isn't it easier to merge only where `indexes` are different rather than merging everything and dropping duplicated after? ;)

Comment: Thanks guys! I will use this on large amounts of data, so efficiency is important indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with indexes that are not in `df2`'s indexes. Let

```
df  = df.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')
```

Then

```
>>> merged = pd.concat([df[~df.index.isin(df2.index)], df2]).reset_index()

    id      value
0   100010  25
1   100011  22
2   100012  35
3   100013  36
```

Comment: With or without the '~'?

Comment: @Hoenie with the `~`, so you get indexes in `df` that are not in `df2`, and combine with the remaining indexes in `df2`

Comment: That's what I thought, but I am getting exactly the opposite

Comment: @Hoenie hm, im pretty sure there's some small mistake or typo in your coce ;0

Comment: Yep, forgot, the `df1 =`  in `df1 = df1.set_index('id')`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

The simplest way is:

```
>>> df1=df1.set_index('id')
>>> df2=df2.set_index('id')
```

use combine_first on `df2`

```
>>> df2.combine_first(df1)
       value
id
100010    25
100011    22
100012    35
100013    36
```

---

OLD post:

As an alternative, you can use the standard python dictionary

```
>>> df1=df1.set_index('id')
>>> df2=df2.set_index('id')
```

make a dictionary out of `df1`

```
>>> d = df1.to_dict( 'index' )
>>> d
{'100012': {'value': '30'}, '100010': {'value': '25'}, '100011': {'value': '22'}}
```

`update()` with the other dataframe dictionary - duplicate keys will be updated with the full row

```
>>> d.update( df2.to_dict( 'index' ) )
>>> d
{'100012': {'value': '35'}, '100013': {'value': '36'}, '100010': {'value': '25'}, '100011': {'value': '22'}}
```

Turn it back into a dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_dict( d, 'index' )
       value
100010    25
100011    22
100012    35
100013    36
```

If you want to keep it all in pandas - RafaelC's solution is better